# Submit unique record with multiple dynamic inputs

Tags: php, forms, foreach

I have been working on a form with the help of many here on SO. I have a form where users get 1 fieldset to fill out with all the inputs initailly. Then they can click ADD MORE or submit the form as is. If they click ADD MORE the users get all of the inputs again and a foreach allows them to be submitted along with the 1st fieldset in 1 submission. There can be as many as the user would like.

The problem is each of the submissions is not unique. They are all lumped together into one submission.

Here is the submit code:

```
 if ($reqtype=="accesschange"){
            $subject="Request Access Change(s)";
            $a=$_REQUEST['request'];        
            foreach ($a as $name) {         
              foreach ($name as $key => $desc) {
                switch (gettype($desc)) {
                  case 'array':
                    foreach ($desc as $i => $item) {                    

                      //show which queue to go to based on C or D
                      $drive = ($item == "File System") ? "162" : "161";

                      $note .= "{$key}";
                      $note .= "&nbsp;".$item."\n";
                    }
                    break;
                  case 'string':
                  default:
                    if ($desc !== '') {                     
                      $note.= $key;
                      $note.= "&nbsp;".$desc."\n";
                    }
                }
              }
                $note .="\n";

                $note = $UP->stripSpecialChars($note);
                $note = $UP->remSlash($note);
                $myxml  = "<connector>";
                $myxml .= "<function name=\"incident_create\">";
                $myxml .= "<pair name=\"lvl_id3\"  type=\"integer\">".$note."</pair>";          
                $myxml .= "</function>";
                $myxml .= "</connector>";       
                echo $myxml;
            }
        }
```

How can I make each of these a unique submission? I have been thinking I need some kind of counter or way to make each of these unique... If this is confusing, let know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A counter would be needed but I would say on your form code not the submit code.

You will need to make sure each of the fields are unique, then submit the form.

Comment: Provide your form code and I will take a look. Basically you need to increment the counter everytime te add more button is pressed.

Comment: Provide your form code and I will take a look. Basically you need to increment the counter everytime te add more button is pressed. This increment will then get added tithe field name so that it is unique. E.g <input type="text" name="nameexample<?php echo $i; ?>" />